# SubSonic Conventions

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I would love to have a list of SubSonic conventions.  I saw http://www.subsonicproject.com/docs/Conventions but it didn't seem complete as of today and it seems wrong.  It says "table names should be singular".

My understanding is that the convention is plural names for table names.

I am also not clear on how to name lookup tables.

Comment: You'll probably get a better response to this sort of question on the mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/subsonicproject

Answer (score 1):

There is a documentation page for the Conventions used in SubSonic.   You can find the page at
[www.subsonicproject.com/docs/Conventions](http://www.subsonicproject.com/docs/Conventions) .  Post any needed information on the SubsonicProject group and I will try to see that it gets answered/added to the convention page.